# Getting ID from URL in another action

Tags: php, cakephp

I got three models

1. User
2. Group
3. Subscription

In Subscriptions table i have three fields

1. id
2. user_id
3. group_id

What i want is that, i want to display the list of all the subscribers of each group right here ( /groups/viewcourse/id )

**GroupsController:**

```
public function viewcourse($id=NULL)
{
    $this->set('viewcourse', $this->Group->read(NULL,$id));
    $this->set('course', $this->Group->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Group.id'=>$id))));


     $this->set('allnotes', $this->Group->Note->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>array('Note.group_id' => $id),'order' => array('Note.created DESC'))))
}
```

**UsersController:**

```
public function subscribers()
{
$subscribers = $this->User->Subscription->find('all',array(
  'conditions'=>array(
  'Subscription.group_id'=>26)
  )
 );
}
```

Now here in the UsersController i want to retrieve the Group Id somehow from URL to place it instead of 26 so that i can display the list of users subscribed to that specific group or group 26.

The only way that come`s in my mind is grabbing the id from URL.

What i tried is adding $this->params['pass'][0] to UsersController ( subscribers action ) but then again it is not taking id from viewcourse as it will only pass the id from subscribers action which is Null and of no use. I want id from  /groups/viewcourse/id.

Comment: Is there a link in your view that the user is clicking to get to the subscribers view from viewcourse? Or are you doing some sort of auto-redirect?

Comment: Yes there is a button for subscription. When the user clicks it, It redirects the user to subscribers view and the subscription is added with the group id in the Subscription table

Answer (score 0):

Just pass another param along with your link helper to the controller.
in the view:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Subscribers', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'subscribers', 'group'=>$viewcourse['Group']['id'])); ?>
```

and retrieve the params in your subscribers function with

```
 $group_id = $this->params['named']['group'];
```

Comment: But the controller in which i made the Subscribers action is UsersController and i want to retrieve the value there rather than SubscriptionsController

Comment: just change the controller to users in the link helper. I updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting your functions that retrieve database information in your Models, not your controllers - then you can access their logic and data from any controller.

**Example code:**

```
//GroupsController
public function viewcourse($id=NULL)
{
    //...
    $this->loadModel('Subscription');
    $subscribers = $this->Subscription->getAllByGroupId($id);
    //...
}

//Subscription model
public function getAllByGroupId($groupId = null) {
    if(empty($groupId)) return false;
    return $this->findAllByGroupId($groupId);
}
```